# firing async call in higher order component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this HOC component where it check if a user has privilege to be redirect to certain route, but I don't know how and where to fire async call.

```
export default function CheckPermission(EnhancedComponent) {
  return class Redirect extends Component {

    render() {

      const special_member_token = '3453564' //hardcoded for temp

      const on_special_member_route = this.props.location.pathname.includes('special_member')

      if (getUserRole() === 'special_member' && !on_applied_route) {

        return <Redirect to={`/dashboard/special_member/${special_member_token}`} />
      }

      return <EnhancedComponent { ...this.props } />
    }
  }
}
```

Call the api in render is an anti pattern, should I do it in `componentDidMount`? But the render has already been trigger once if I call in `componentDidMount`, I have to avoid the wrapped component being render at all if the redirect have to happens.

Comment: set a state.loading@true & your async call in componentWillMount, just render a message when state.loading. On your async callback set state.loading@false

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire async call in two methods:

1) `componentWillMount` - component not rendered yet.
2) `componentWillUpdate` - maybe your app url changed and this component receive new props and will be update and need to check user priveleges